# map file in mapserver

Tags: c#, mapserver

I am working with mapserver and c#
can anybody plz explain what does these line mean

```
function AddLayers()
{
var districtBase = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer(
        "District2",
        app.mapserverUrl() + "District2.map",
        { format: "OpenLayers.Format.Vector" },
        { isBaseLayer: true, singleTile: true, ratio: 1.5, transparent: 'true', opacity: .8}
    );
}
```

District2.map means a mapfile in mapserver?

app.mapserverUrl() + "District2.map means what?

Comment: Read this http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html#setting-up-a-wms-server-using-mapserver and especially what it tells about the online resource URL in MapServer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*mapserverUrl()* must be a function that returns the mapserver.exe directory, where the Mapserver is installed, and *"District2.map"* is the Mapserver configuration file, the Mapfile.
please check: http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/